# В чем может быть проблема c foreach?

Tags: php

```
$query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM task WHERE user_task="'.$user.'"';
        foreach ($parameters as $key=>$val) {
            if (!$key || !$key%2) $query .= ' AND '.$val.'="';
            else $query .= $val.'"';
        }
        echo $query;
//SELECT COUNT(*) FROM task WHERE user_task="2" AND status_task="0"status_task"1"
```

Почему такой результат???? Должен же быть:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM task WHERE user_task="2" AND status_task="0" AND status_task="1"
```

Comment: причем тут javascript?

Comment: javascript машинально

Comment: А вот это зачем `if (!$key || !$key%2)`? У вас ВСЕ поля добавляемые в цикле должны иметь префиксом `AND`

Comment: Не говоря уж о том, что собирать SQL таким образом - это самый надёжный способ выстрелить себе в ногу

Comment: судя по тому, что добавилось в конец без пробела строка, то выполнился код $query .= $val.'"'; следовательно if (!$key || !$key%2) не выполнилось

Comment: @rjhdby, Ваш способ помог

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну разберите свой код по порядку и все станет на место.

Первая итерация: `!0 || !0%2 => !(false) || !(false) => true || true => true`

Вторая итерация: `!1 || ... => !(true) || ... => false || ... => false`

Третья итерация: `!2 || ... => !(true) || ... => false || ... => false`

Как видите, результат всегда отрицательный и не зависит от того, что у Вас идет после первой проверки. В итоге будет только один `AND` в самом начале и дальше все будет сплошной строкой. Поэтому в случае ошибок на простых блоках проверяйте свой алгоритм на правильность, если не в уме, то хотя бы на бумаге расписывая его правильность.

И да, это небезопасный способ составления запросов, так как содержит уязвимисти и приложение можно легко взломать хакеру. Используйте [подготовленные запросы для PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepared-statements.php) или [подготовленные запросы для mysqli](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Спасибо, || подвело. Не подумал об этом. А документацию сейчас почитаю

Comment: Почитал. Так это я ими и пользуюсь. Сейчас просто формировал строку для $pdo->query($query);
$pdo->prepare($query) нет смысла писать, так как все данные генерирует php

Comment: @vKs ну сейчас я вижу напрямую вшитые параметры, как например `$query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM task WHERE user_task="'.$user.'"'`. Хотя параметры должны быть добавлены через связывание: `$query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM task WHERE user_task=:user'` и потом дальше в коде `$stmt->bindParam(':user', $user);`. Ладно, просто я привык, что если нет смысла, то все равно делаю как полагается на всякий случай - мало ли что потом поменяется.